# How to get data from package.json in next.js

Tags: next.js

I was wondering if I could access data from package.json inside my .env file to use them inside my project like this?

```
const appVersion = process.env.APP_VERSION
const appName = process.env.APP_NAME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding some configuration to next.config.js

```
env: {
    npm_package_name: process.env.npm_package_name,
    npm_package_version: process.env.npm_package_version,
  },
```

then accessing app version and name like so:

```
const APP_NAME = process.env.npm_package_name,
const APP_VERSION = process.env.npm_package_version
```